# Inflate layout in an activity with PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-inflate

My custom `FragmentSettings()` extends `android.preference.PreferenceFragment` and I simply add it in my activity.

I want to inflate (add) as well the `layout.logo` which has gravity:bottom. However with my code the inflated `layout.logo` is not visible. I guess because I use `inflate()` with `getFragmentManager()`? How can I correctly add a layout in this case?

```
public class ActivitySettings  extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentSettings details = new FragmentSettings();
        details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.logo, null );
    }


}
```

PS: `R.layout.logo` is an ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentSettings details = new FragmentSettings();
    details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.logo, null);
    // may be logo is a layout file, if not then put your layout file which contain an ImageView
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}
```

but you said that `R.layout.logo` in an `ImageView` . you know, `ImageView` has an id and you will find it from `R.id.(your ImageView's id )` hear. just i assume that  `imageView1` is and id of your `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Firstly the ImageView is going to be the same in all cases so it's fine. Secondly what is (/how do you declare the variable) `context` in your answer? I tried `LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());` without success.

Comment: Context context; is global variable . you can declare it in your activity class before onCreate() .